# Disabling main page url from robots.txt

Tags: seo, robots.txt

Example robots.txt:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Would it work? I have urls, like https://example.com/en, https://example.com/de

I don't want search engines to index https://example.com without language prefix. Is that possible?

Comment: Whatever reason you have to do this, it is not good practice.
You should have one version of the website as a "default", when it comes to languages, and .com is perfect for that purpose.
I would rethink this, if I was you.

Comment: You mean, for example: https://example.com which defaults to english by default? But i have https://example.com/en for that.

Comment: Bear in mind that there are different versions of english as well, so this is not necessarily sufficient. Have a look at hreflang best practices https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en perhaps you will get a better picture.

Comment: I already added hreflangs to all of my pages, but google seems to ignore them, when i search my website, i get english and german results together, though my region is set to US.

Comment: I'd love to see what it looks like, perhaps I would have better understanding of what you are trying to achieve and why. Perhaps you can send me DM.

Comment: Here's the link: https://izi.me

Comment: Had a look at it, there are some issues with loading, but I guess you are still in development mode. 
If you set your robots.txt file to look like:
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
It would block the whole website from crawlers, so this is not what you are looking for.
In any case, I strongly suggest you give up the idea of hiding the home page, as this is the most important page on your website, and i can't see how you can benefit from this.

Answer (score 2):

`Disallow: /` will prevent robots from crawling your entire site.  Robots.txt rules are "starts with" rules. Google and other search engines allow some extensions to robots.txt rules such as wild cards and ends with operators.   For the robots (including Google) that follow those extensions you could use:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /$
```

Most robots will still crawl your home page because they don't understand the `$` "ends with" operators, but search engine bots should stop crawling just your home page while still crawling the rest of your site.

Another problem is that blocking crawling doesn't always prevent indexing.   Google indexes disallowed pages when they have lots of incoming links to them.  It won't index, the content of the page, but it show a link to the page in the search results using keywords from the domain name and external link anchor text.

A better option would be to include the tag `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">` in your root page while allowing it to be crawled.  That would 100% prevent search engines from including it in their search indexes.

I would suggest that you should have a root page that is crawlable and indexable.  It should just allow users to choose their language.   When a users language can be identefied from the `Accept-Language` header, you could automatically redirect them.   For bots that don't send `Accept-Language` headers and users that don't have a matching language, you could display a list of languages to choose from.   This is what some big sites like Ikea do.

Comment: Thank you, so, basically i just need a page for crawlers/unmatched `navigator.language` strings to let them choose a language, right?

Comment: Yes, that would be a good way of doing it.

Comment: But then crawlers would index this page with language choices?

Comment: That page isn't going to have many words on it, so it probably isn't going to rank for very much.  The only real possibility would be that it ranks for your brand name.  You could mitigate that be using `hreflang` with `x-default` on that page and point the other languages to the directories.  See https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2013/04/x-default-hreflang-for-international-pages.html   Even if it did get indexed for your brand name, it wouldn't be horrible user experience.   At most users would have to make an extra click.  With auto-redirects, most users wouldn't even have to do that.

Answer (score 0):

As most answers already said here, I wouldn't recommend doing this, but one way to do would be to set up a 301 redirect to your "main" language (https://example.com/en for example).

Every website needs a default page, so you should choose one and then redirect to it.